# removing the tryCatch code from my results

Tags: r, rvest

I'm using the following code to get the jobs description through the job links that I get from a data frame (named as listings):

```
#obtain full description for all job postings

    for (i in (1:length(listings$link))){
      desciption <- tryCatch(
        html_text(html_node(read_html(as.character(listings$link[i])),'.jobsearch-JobComponent-description')),
        error=function(e){NA}
      )
      if (is.null(desciption)){
        desc <- NA
      }
      return(desciption)
      listings$description[i] <- desciption
    }
```

I get the description, however, the rows include also the tryCatch code, as shown here:

```
"Gormley, ONFull-time, Contract$25 an hour try   window.mosaic.onMosaicApiReady(function()   var zoneId = 'aboveFullJobDescription'; var providers = window.mosaic.zonedProviders[zoneId]; if (providers)   providers.filter(function(p)   return window.mosaic.lazyFns[p]; }).forEach(function(p)   return window.mosaic.api.loadProvider(p); }); } }); } catch (e)  }; Brake Mobile Wash is one of the largest mobile pressure washing companies in Ontario. We specialize in mobile pressure washing large commercial fleets across Ontario and Manitoba. We are currently looking for a Business Analyst to work out of our Gormley office.Job Responsibilities:Work alongside the Operations Manager to understand the business and the industryStudy and research current operations and structuresAnalyze maintenance and service history to look for past inefficiencies and develop a detailed maintenance program and forecast future service intervalsDevelop an in depth strategic business plan to present to management that includes direction and recommended improvementsDevelop strategies to reduce expensesImproving data to support daily operational activities and decision makingQualifications:Experienced as a business analyst or junior business analyst or similar role; knowledge of business analysis best practices is an assetPost-secondary education in economics, business or financeKnowledge of business and management principles involved in strategic planning, resource allocation, and project management methods.Ability to analyze business trends and project future revenues and expensesKnowledge of business plan and business model developmentProficiency in MS Office (e.g. Outlook, Word, Excel, PowerPoint, etc.)Good understanding of the transportation industry and commercial vehicles· Valid Driver’s license and access to a personal vehicle is requiredContract length: 6 weeksJob Types: Full-time, ContractSalary: $25.00 /hourEducation:Secondary School (Required) try   window.mosaic.onMosaicApiReady(function()   var zoneId = 'belowFullJobDescription'; var providers = window.mosaic.zonedProviders[zoneId]; if (providers)   providers.filter(function(p)   return window.mosaic.lazyFns[p]; }).forEach(function(p)   return window.mosaic.api.loadProvider(p); }); } }); } catch (e)  };"
```

Can you please suggest to me what to do to maintain only the content (only the description)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you had in mind, but you can remove the trycatch stuff with a regexp. This will work provided that all the descriptions start with the same pattern. `listings$description[i]  <- gsub("window\\.mosaic\\.\\S.*?catch \\(e\\) \\};", "", desciption)`

Comment: I'm not sure why you are returning the description before the for end.probably for debugging purposes.

Comment: Is there an url to use for testing and what should the output be exactly in the above?

Comment: Thank you for your help guys, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I have found based on your suggestion @DDJ :)

for (i in seq(1, length(listings$description))) {

```
listings$description[i] <- gsub("window\\.mosaic\\.\\S.*?catch \\(e\\) \\};", "", listings$description[i])
listings$description[i]<-gsub("try window.mosaic.onMosaicApiReady function   var zoneId =  aboveFullJobDescription ; var providers = window.mosaic.zonedProviders zoneId ; if  providers  providers.filter function p  return window.mosaic.lazyFns p ;  .forEach function p  return window.mosaic.api.loadProvider p ;  ;  ; catch  e  ; ", " ", listings$description[i])
listings$description[i]<-gsub("try window.mosaic.onMosaicApiReady function   var zoneId =  belowFullJobDescription ; var providers = window.mosaic.zonedProviders zoneId ; if  providers  providers.filter function p  return window.mosaic.lazyFns p ;  .forEach function p  return window.mosaic.api.loadProvider p ;  ;  ; catch  e  ;", " ", listings$description[i]) 
}
```